# jQuery Insert Character at specific Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have an element such as:

```
<input type="text" id="TestingElement" />
```

Now, this element is supposed to take in Dates (I know of jQuery datepicker, and bootstrap so this doesn't concern them).  Is there a way for me to just type in 08251999 or 082599, and then when the user clicks outside of the text-box or it loses focus, that there can be two `/` characters inserted.  One `/` character inserted after `08` and the next `/` character inserted after `25`, resulting in `08/25/1999`, or `08/25/99`?  I have been looking at `.append()` and `.insertAfter` but those seem to only help in adding elements before/after the element that you specified, not within.

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnj3y32f/) to help with the testing process.

Thank you in advance and any help is appreciated!

Comment: i think you can handle `.focusout()` event to do that

Comment: Sounds like you should use a masking plugin, not a datepicker

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have come across [this](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) and that will work!  Is there an available URI for me to test within my JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisCoray/hLkjhsce/

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid yep, google 'jQuery mask CDN' and you get this: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.mask

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbxaaz60/) with the URI that you provided and upgraded the jQuery to 2.1.3, but this isn't working?  Know of a reason?

Comment: You don't need the `blur` event handler: https://jsfiddle.net/xbxaaz60/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ahh well that makes sense.. silly me.  If you post the answer I will accept it! Thank you!

Comment: That's ok, the answer went completely off topic of your original question so you're probably best to just delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save this question for reference purposes Rory McCrossan was able to help me tremendously by suggesting a masking plugin.

Going to this [address](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.mask) helped and I referenced this address as the `src` for my scripts.  It is working exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help:

```
 text.substring(0,2)+"/"+text.substring(2,4)+"/"+text.substring(4,6)
```